# MySQL - Regular expression search works properly when matching rows are found and not otherwise

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, database

I have the following query:

```
SELECT 
    item_id, rate, sum(qty) as 'qty', prate, specs 
FROM 
    stockmain INNER JOIN stockdetail ON stockmain.stid = stockdetail.stid 
WHERE `serial` RLIKE '(\s)*exists(\s)*'
```

It works fine i.e. fetches the records when the serial `exists` exists in the table. But it keeps returning a row of `NULL` entries when a matching value isn't found i.e. result looks like the following:

```
+--------------------------------------------------+
|  item_id  |   rate    | qty   | prate   | specs  |
+--------------------------------------------------+
|  NULL     |  NULL     |  NULL | NULL    |  NULL  |
+--------------------------------------------------+
```

So I modified the above query like so

```
SELECT 
    item_id, rate, sum(qty) as 'qty', prate, specs 
FROM 
    stockmain INNER JOIN stockdetail ON stockmain.stid = stockdetail.stid 
WHERE `serial` RLIKE '(\s)*exists(\s)*' AND item_id <> ''
```

But still it keeps returning this `NULL` entries row. I have tried `''`,`NULL`, `FALSE` and `IS NOT NULL` in place of `AND item_id <> ''` but none of them works.

Is there any way that I can get rid of this `row` that keeps returning when no records are found and get an empty result if the `serial` doesn't match anything?

Comment: What you tried adding `AND (item_id <> '' or item_ID IS NOT NULL)`?

Comment: Yes it didn't work either

Comment: does your table enforce columns to be `NOT NULL`? if not it is possible that you actually have row with `NULL` values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your query:

```
SELECT item_id, rate, sum(qty) as 'qty', prate, specs 
FROM stockmain INNER JOIN
     stockdetail
     ON stockmain.stid = stockdetail.stid 
WHERE `serial` RLIKE '(\s)*exists(\s)*';
```

Because the of the `sum(qty)`, this is an aggregation query.  An aggregation will always return a row, even with no matches.  With no matches, the values will be `NULL` (as in your results).

You probably mean either this:

```
SELECT item_id, rate, sum(qty) as qty, prate, specs 
FROM stockmain INNER JOIN
     stockdetail
     ON stockmain.stid = stockdetail.stid 
WHERE `serial` RLIKE '(\s)*exists(\s)*'
GROUP BY item_id, rate, prate, specs;
```

Or:

```
SELECT item_id, rate, qty, prate, specs 
FROM stockmain INNER JOIN
     stockdetail
     ON stockmain.stid = stockdetail.stid 
WHERE `serial` RLIKE '(\s)*exists(\s)*'
```